# iOS - how to display such subview and progress Indicator (image attached)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7

How would i achieve the following :

[image][image]

I have no idea what they are or how to replicate them.

The left one is some kind of transparent view that appears over the page and the right one is a square box that appears while the app is processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, try a semi-transparent subview brought to the front of other subviews and then other subviews for content. Or, take an image of the underlying view and push a modal view with that image as the background with other views over it to get the visual style you want.

For the second, take a look at [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

Answer (score 2):

Uh...

1) Is aUIView with a big black background with an opacity of 0.9

2) Is the UIActivityViewIndicator on top of another black 0.9 opaque view with rounded corners,e.g:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *av = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
```